# Why can't I get my site to recognize a default error page for status code 404 in a WebMatrix WebPages environment?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, webmatrix, custom-error-pages, asp.net-webpages

I have seen in multiple places

[here]
http://www.localwisdom.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-setup-custom-404s-for-iis-and-asp-net-through-web-config/

[and from a previous question here]
[How can I make a custom error page in ASP.NET web-pages with WebMatrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957954/how-can-i-make-a-custom-error-page-in-asp-net-web-pages-with-webmatrix)

how to setup the web.config file to force custom error pages for given status codes (I *think* the only ones I care about are "500" and "404").

I am using this as the `<system.web>` element in the web.config XML.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"><assemblies><add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /></assemblies></compilation>
    <customErrors mode="On">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error.cshtml" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error404.cshtml" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

The custom error page for the status code, "500" serves up just fine on normal server-side errors, but for some reason, no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the custom error page for status code "404" to show up if, say, a broken link were clicked on the page. Instead, it just shows the normal "404, resource not found" default page.

I have also tried to change the order of the `<error>` tags (not that that *should* help, but as you can see, I am out of reasonable things to try, LOL).

Am I misunderstanding how this whole thing works or am I simply getting the configuration/syntax wrong in some way?

**--------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------**

Okay, so apparently, my custom 404 page works if a normal link is broken, however, I have `.cs` file with certain html generating methods in it.

On a single secondary page, this will be it's entire contents:

```
@Html.Raw(ContentGenerator.Generate("CityCouncil"))
```

The values for what to display on the page come from a database, are encoded as they are added to the string, and then written to the page. If the C# string contains a broken link, then the default error page does not show up. Why should this make a difference? My guess is, it's a timing issue, and that by the time C# writes the HTML to the page, the web.config file can no longer influence this link or something.

Is there any way to still achieve a default error page for these links?

Comment: Does your error404.cshtml file get served if you add an extension to the url? eg htp://locahost:<port>/doesntexist.cshtml

Comment: @MikeBrind Yes, if I path to it directly, it shows up just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `customErrors` entry in your web.config under `system.web` works for urls with file extensions as we have established. but to work for extension-less urls, you need to override IIS by adding an entry to the `system.webServer` node in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath=""
               path="/Error404.cshtml" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Having done this, you also need to move any other custom error handling to the `system.webServer` section and remove the `customErrors` entry under `system.web`.

Comment: Hi, Mike. Thanks for shedding some light on this for me. I'm trying this now. I noticed that you have `path="/Error404.cshtml"`, do I not want that to be `path="~/Error404.cshtml"` (notice the tilde)? I ask because I noticed that the tilde was included in other urls in the web.config file, and while I could test this myself, I thought you might want to know in case you wanted to change that in your answer (if it is, indeed, even relevant).

Comment: Okay, so I tried this and it totally worked (thank you, again for that!), but I just wanted to clarify a couple of things for my education's sake, if you don't mind. Firstly, though, I just want to say (concerning my comment above), that the tilde, included here, should definitely be excluded, as it will not generate a valid path if the error occurs. Now, first question: "I used subStatusCode="-1" in the error for statusCode 500. This works but wanted to make sure that was right, since I'm not sure what a subStatusCode even is." And for the second question:...(continued)

Comment: (continued)..."You stated that this was all necessary because of my use of 'extension-less' urls, but the urls generated from the C# file included the file extension (example: /someDir/somePic.jpg). Am I misunderstanding what you mean by 'extension-less'?"

Comment: I assumed that you had problems getting your custom page to display when you requested a cshtml file without its extension. IIS sees that as a missing directory. However, for missing static files (.html, .jpg, .txt etc) the solution is the same - to set the custom error page in the `system.webServer` section to prevent IIS default behaviour.

Comment: Okay, I see, well you certainly solved my problem. So there's nothing wrong with using `subStatusCode="-1"` for statusCode 500?

Comment: It's the default subStatusCode value for IIS, so it's fine, and probably actually not needed. Removing it will make no difference.